# Как вернуть в методе абстрактного класса наследуемый класс C#

Tags: c#, ооп, наследование

У меня есть класс Parent и наследуемые от него Childs.
У них есть собственные поля и методы. Но если использовать такой код, то доступа к ним нет:

```
abstract class Parent{
   public Parent Open()
   {
      *действие*
      return this;
   }
}
class Child : Parent{
public int num;
}
```

Теперь я хочу вызвать `new Child().Open().num`, но оно не работает.
Что сделать?

Comment: Parent в вашем коде не содержит определения num. Для доступа к полям нужно примерно такое сделать ```new Child().num``` и ```new Child().Open()```

Comment: А если у меня наследуются 10 классов по 10 полей? я же не буду каждый так обьявлять?

Comment: Можно определить виртуальное свойство в базовом классе, обратиться к полю так как вы это делаете нельзя

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, такого язык C# покамест не умеет, хотя предложение о поддержке таких конструкций [обсуждалось](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/252). `Open` возвращает `Parent`, т. к. не знает ничего о `Child`.

Вам придётся либо явно преобразовывать тип к `Child`, либо отказаться от fluent-синтаксиса:

```
abstract class Parent
{
    public void Open()
    {
        // *действие*
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public int num;
}
```

```
var c = new Child();
c.Open();
c.num = 1;
```

Ещё одно, на мой вкус избыточно сложное решение, состоит в применении идиомы [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://ericlippert.com/2011/02/02/curiouser-and-curiouser/):

```
class Parent<TSelf> where TSelf : Parent<TSelf>
{
    public TSelf Open()
    {
        // *действие*
        return (TSelf)this;
    }
}

class Child : Parent<Child>
{
    public int num;
}
```

При этом вы таки сможете написать

```
new Child().Open().num = 1;
```

Но я не рекомендовал бы идти этим путём, он открывает ящик Пандоры. Например, никто не помешает вам написать `class Evil : Parent<Child>` и получить исключение.

Comment: Очень жаль что он так не умеет. Спасибо.

Comment: А что плохого в получении исключения при использовании class Evil : Parent<Child>?

Comment: 9-й C# умеет covariant return types :)

Comment: @PashaPash: Да, но это не спасает из коробки. Хотя, конечно, помогает.

Comment: @Egorrko: В том, что такие исключения хотелось бы предотвратить на синтаксическом уровне, а не дожидаться ошибки во время выполнения,

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант заменить поле на абстрактное свойство:

```
abstract class Parent
{
    public abstract int num { get; set; }
    public Parent Open() => this;
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public override int num { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Child cld = new Child();
        cld.num = 4;
        Console.WriteLine(cld.Open().num);
    }
}
```

Вариант с виртуальным свойством:

```
abstract class Parent
{
    public virtual int num { get; set; }
    public Parent Open => this;
}

class Child : Parent
{
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Child cld = new Child();
        cld.num = 4;
        Console.WriteLine(cld.Open.num);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если идти по этому пути, то лучше, наверное, абстрактное?

Comment: Да, пожалуй лучше абстрактное, сейчас поправлю

Comment: Спасибо за ваше решение, но я в большом масштабе это к сожалению не вариант.

Comment: Попробуйте abstract заменить на virtual и полностью убрать override из дочернего класса. Поведение кода в Main сохранится, возможно такой вариант Вас устроит.

Answer (score 3):

Если у вас C# 9 (.NET 5), то можно использовать Covariant Return. Объявить метод базового класса как `virtual`, и переопределить тип возвората в `Child`:

```
abstract class Parent
{
    public virtual Parent Open()
    {
       // *действие *
       return this;
    }
}
class Child : Parent
{
    public int num = 5;

    public override Child Open() => (Child)base.Open();
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new Child().Open().num);
    }
}
```

Тип придется переопределять в каждом наследнике, по необходимости.В более старых версиях языка работать не будет.